# Read() statement for data containing, char, integer and real with FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

How can I change this code for it to work?

```
real(8), dimension(11), intent(inout) :: x 
integer(4) :: idx 
character(len=4) :: fake_read_first
character(len=4) :: fake_read_second
integer(4) :: fake_index 

do idx = 1_idp, n, 1_idp 
    read(nfile, FMT="(a,i5,a,f28.18)") fake_read_first, fake_index, &
             fake_read_second, x(idx) ! read line wise
end do
```

It reads data on a file that has the following form (with  spaces as it is)

```
eps(    1) =        -1.534875443410773865
eps(    2) =         1.879729927704710146
eps(    3) =        -1.141802880301361789
eps(    4) =        -0.762516225079661325
eps(    5) =        -0.698569538839495241
eps(    6) =         1.000000000000000000
eps(    7) =         1.918166206055258449
eps(    8) =         0.321720085182322979
eps(    9) =        -1.325650752925679132
eps(   10) =        -1.596179600738307780
eps(   11) =         1.786605261597484340
```

I am getting the following error:

```
At line 90 of file ddnls_mlce_thps_main.f90 (unit = 10, file = 
'__init_ddnls_mlce_thps__.ini')
Fortran runtime error: Bad value during integer read
```

Comment: If you don't need the variable `fake_index`, you can use unformatted ("`*`") read:  `read(nfile, *) fake_a, fake_b, fake_c, x(idx)` that will split the line based on spaces.

Comment: Note that `real(8)` and `integer(4)` are ugly, not portable and your code will not compile with certain compilers.

Comment: this actually works just fine. Are you sure the entire file has that column structure? (and really spaces, not tabs )  (I would do as @PierredeBuyl says anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: Your code seems to work. Check whether your data file conforms to the format you've given us **on every line**.

Secondly: There are many ways to read such data. You can do what you did and use dummy variables that get discarded after each read.

What I would do, because I think it makes things easy to understand in the code (which I think is very valuable) is to read each line into a string, find the `=` in that string, then read the values out of that string. Here's an example:

```
program read_data
    use iso_fortran_env, only: int32, real64
    implicit none
    real(kind=real64) :: x(11)
    character(len=100) :: line
    integer(kind=int32) :: idx, start_pos
    integer :: u

    open(newunit=u, file='data.txt', action='read', status='old')

    do idx = 1, size(x), 1
        read(u, '(A)') line
        start_pos = index(line, '=') + 1
        read(line(start_pos:), *) x(idx)
    end do

    close(u)

    print '(F24.18)', x

end program read_data
```

You might want to introduce some error checking: Check the `iostat` and `iomsg` values from the `open` and `read` statements. Check whether there is actually an `=` sign in the line by checking whether `start_pos` is larger than 1 (`index` returns 0 if the substring is not found).